# iOS 9 + Parse | .fetchIfNeeded() error in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

Since updating my app to Swift 2.0 and the latest Xcode 7, I get the following error on all of my lines of code with "fetchIfNeeded()"

[image]

How do I fix this? I cannot find a changelog or reason this is now broken?

Comment: Have you tried re-writing any of the lines that give you a problem to see how the method wants to be called now? What if it can throw? You should add some code to your question as well.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this now is below, seeing as `fetchIfNeeded()` now `throws`.

```
do {
    try notification?.fetchIfNeeded()
} catch _ {
   print("There was an error")         
}
```

Your other option is to use `fetchIfNeededInBackground()` which doesn't require the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

The objectForKey returns AnyObject? and needs to be casted to PFObject

```
do {
    try (notification?.objectForKey("post") as! PFObject).fetchIfNeeded()
} catch _ {
    print("There was an error")         
}
```